# Loading specific div based on the results of multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, onclick, listitem

EDIT: Would the approach be much easier if the Javascript listed was removed completely, and the dropdown menus restyled as `<div>`'s within `<li>`'s, and the final div was generated by a Javascript onclick event? e.g.

```
    <a id="click_link">click me</a>

       $("#click_link").click(function(){
       $('#div').load('http://www.link.com/');
    });
```

---

Either way, the problem at hand...

My decision to use an elegant-looking javascript solution is highlighting my massive inexperience when it comes to javascript! The problem is, on the face of it, simple...

Once an option has been chosen on each of the dropdown menus, I need a final div to load so that a specific button can be shown (a link to buy the item with the specified options, e.g. choosing Necklace D, with Stone Option B, and Delivery Option A = loading div with 'Buy' Button #17)

The dropdowns are divs that are filled and styled through the Javascript (as opposed to using the simpler `<form>` and `<input>` method), giving the flexibility to add two lines of differently styled text for each option etc. - This is where I step into the realm of the unknown and my inexperience shines through.

The isolated section is viewable in its entirity [here](http://www.mennalloyd.com/test/buytest.html)

Ok, to the code.
Here's the Javascript:

```
function createByJson() {
    var pearlData = [                   
                    {description:'Choose your pearl...', value:'Pearls', text:'Pearls'},
                    {description:'Beautiful black stone', value:'Black Pearl', text:'Black Pearl'},
                    {description:'Classic white stone', value:'White Pearl', text:'White Pearl'}
                    ];
    $("#DropItPearls").msDropDown({byJson:{data:pearlData, name:'pearls', width: 200}}).data("dd"); 
        var blodeuweddData = [          
                    {description:'Choose your item...', value:'Blodeuwedd', text:'the Blodeuwedd Collection'},
                    {description:'A striking statement', value:'BlodeuweddCelticStatement', text:'Celtic Statement Piece'},
                    {description:'Gold laced flower and pearl', value:'BlodeuweddBracelet', text:'Bracelet'},
                    ];
    $("#DropItBlodeuwedd").msDropDown({byJson:{data:blodeuweddData, name:'blodeuwedd', width: 250}})
                                                            .msDropDown({on:{change:function(data, ui) {
                                                                                                                                                                    var val = data.value;
                                                                                                                                                                    if(val!="")
                                                                                                                                                                        window.location = val;
                                                                                                                                                                }}}).data("dd");
        var deliveryData = [                    
                    {description:'Choose your method...', value:'Delivery', text:'Delivery Options'},
                    {description:'4-6 weeks delivery', value:'Four Weeks', text:'Made To Order'},
                    {description:'(unavailable on this item)', value:'Rush', text:'Express Delivery', disabled:true}
                    ];
    $("#DropItDelivery").msDropDown({byJson:{data:deliveryData, name:'delivery', width: 200, selectedIndex: 1}}).data("dd");
         paymentData = [                    
                    {                                                                                                                               description:'How would you like to pay?', value:'Payment', text:'Payment Method'},
                    {image:'images/msdropdown/icons/Visa-56.png', description:'Secure online payment', value:'Visa', text:'Visa'},
                    {image:'images/msdropdown/icons/Paypal-56.png', description:'Secure online payment', value:'Paypal', text:'Paypal'},
                    {image:'images/msdropdown/icons/EmailPay-56.png', description:'Order by email', value:'Email Payment', text:'Send Your Details'},
                    {image:'images/msdropdown/icons/Mastercard-56.png', description:'(coming soon)', value:'Mastercard', text:'Mastercard', disabled:true},
                    {image:'images/msdropdown/icons/Collect-56.png', description:'(coming soon)', value:'Collection', text:'Order and Collect', disabled:true},
                    {image:'images/msdropdown/icons/Email-56.png', description:'email Menna', value:'Other Method', text:'Alternatives'}
                    ];
    $("#DropItPayments").msDropDown({byJson:{data:paymentData, name:'payments', width: 250}}).data("dd");
    }
    $(document).ready(function(e) { 
    //no use
    try {
        var pages = $("#pages").msDropdown({on:{change:function(data, ui) {
                                                var val = data.value;
                                                if(val!="")
                                                    window.location = val;
                                            }}}).data("dd");
        var pagename = document.location.pathname.toString();
        pagename = pagename.split("/");
        pages.setIndexByValue(pagename[pagename.length-1]);
        $("#ver").html(msBeautify.version.msDropdown);
    } catch(e) {
        //console.log(e);   
    }

    $("#ver").html(msBeautify.version.msDropdown);

    //convert
    $("select").msDropdown();
    createByJson();
    $("#tech").data("dd");
});
function showValue(h) {
    console.log(h.name, h.value);
}
$("#tech").change(function() {
    console.log("by jquery: ", this.value);
})
//
```

And the html:

```
<div id="dropOptions">
    <div id="dropOptionsTitle"><p>Item</p></div>
    <div id="DropItBlodeuwedd"></div>
</div>

<div id="dropOptions">
    <div id="dropOptionsTitle"><p>Precious Stones</p></div>
    <div id="DropItPearls"></div>
</div>

<div id="dropOptions">
     <div id="dropOptionsTitle"><p>Payment</p></div>
    <div id="DropItPayments"></div>
</div>

<div id="dropOptions">
    <div id="dropOptionsTitle"><p>Delivery</p></div>
     <div id="DropItDelivery"></div>
</div>

<div id="dropOptions">
    <div id="dropOptionsTitle"><p>Buy Now!</p></div>
     <div id="DropItBuy"></div>
</div>
```

Again, working version viewable [here](http://www.mennalloyd.com/test/buytest.html)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want is for your Buy button to dynamically read what the dropdowns currently say and build a link for redirection based on that, rather than trying to update the Buy button every time a dropdown changes.

From your code I can't see what the form of the final URL is supposed to be. For example, to get the current value of the delivery option, you can check `$('#DropItDelivery :selected').text()` which will be something like `"Made To Order"`.

Your Buy Now! could be a `button` with a `click` event that reads these values and constructs the URL with basic string concatenation, e.g.:

```
window.location = "buynow.html?delivery=" + $('#DropItDelivery :selected').text() +
                  "&payment=" + $('#DropItPayments :selected').text()
                  // etc.
```

Of course you'd have to handle these options on the server.

In case you want to redirect to the payment page of the processor, you can just branch based on the payment method and give them the URL you want based on that.

```
var pm = $('#DropItPayments :selected').text();
if (pm == "Visa")
{
    // Visa payment URL construction
}
else if (pm == "Send Your Details")
{
    // Send your details URL construction
}
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the approach. My only doubt lies in, as you mentioned, the form the final URL is supposed to be - depending on the payment option chosen the URL will have to:

A) redirect to a Paypal/VISA payment page

B) send an email, inviting further discussion on custom options before payment.

In essence, it will either redirect to a specific URL for item '103.2' (Necklace D, SubOption A, SubOption B) orrrrrrrr send an email via PHP with the results of the dropdown choices.

Comment: @Lewis updated with an example of branching based on payment processor .